# How to test Spring @EventListener method?

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I have some event publishing:

```
@Autowired private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
...
publisher.publishEvent(new MyApplicationEvent(mySource));
```

I have this event listener:

```
class MyApplicationEventHandler {

    @Autowired SomeDependency someDependency;

    @EventListener public void processEvent(final MyApplicationEvent event) {
        // handle event...
    }
}
```

I need to test it using EasyMock. Is there a simple way to publish something in test and assert that my event listener did something?

EDIT:

I tried to create mock test like this:

```
// testing class
SomeDependency someDependency = mock(SomeDependency.class);

MyApplicationEventHandler tested = new MyApplicationEventHandler(someDependency);

@Autowired private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

@Test
public void test() {
    someDependency.doSomething(anyObject(SomeClass.class));
    replay();
    publisher.publishEvent(new MyApplicationEvent(createMySource()));
}
```

It didn't work.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    SomeDependency.doSomething(<any>): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Comment: you want to test the functionality inside this method or you want to test whether this method is being called on this event or not?

Comment: Just whether it has been called or not.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot or vanilla spring?

Comment: Just inject a mock `ApplicationEventPublisher` and check if the `publish` method gets called. Anything else and you are testing the framework.

Comment: I use SpringBoot with EasyMock.

Comment: @M.Deinum is stating correctly that the test you are asking to create is more of an integration test, that tests that Spring is behaving properly when an event is published.  You should be able to assume this is true and simply unit test your own logic with calls to your event listener.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, As you're using Spring Boot, the testing of these becomes pretty straightforward.  This test will spin up the boot context and inject a real instance of ApplicationEventPublisher, but create a mocked instance of SomeDependency.  The test publishes the desired event, and verifies that your mock was invoked as you expected.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EventPublisherTest {

   @Autowired 
   private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

   @MockBean
   private SomeDependency someDependency;

   @Test
   public void test() {
      publisher.publishEvent(new MyApplicationEvent(createMySource()));

      // verify that your method in you 
      verify(someDependency, times(1)).someMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is this `verify` method from?

Comment: `import static org.mockit.Mockito.verify;`

Comment: I use kotlin and I get an unitialized error for publisher instance even if I autowire it.

Answer (score 12):

In case, spinning up the whole Spring context is not an option, with Spring Boot 2.0.0 `ApplicationContextRunner` was introduced.

`ApplicationContextRunner` can create an application context in your test, allowing for more control over the context.

A complete test example could be:

```java
package net.andreaskluth.context.sample;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.runner.ApplicationContextRunner;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class SimpleEventTest {

  private final ApplicationContextRunner runner = new ApplicationContextRunner();

  @Test
  public void happyPathSuccess() {
    AtomicBoolean sideEffectCausedByEvent = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    ObservableEffect effect = () -> sideEffectCausedByEvent.set(true);

    runner
        .withBean(SomeEventListener.class, effect)
        .run(
            context -> {
              context.publishEvent(new SomeEvent());
              assertThat(sideEffectCausedByEvent.get()).isTrue();
            });
  }

  public interface ObservableEffect {
    void effect();
  }

  @Component
  public static class SomeEventListener {

    private final ObservableEffect effect;

    public SomeEventListener(ObservableEffect effect) {
      this.effect = effect;
    }

    @EventListener(SomeEvent.class)
    public void listen() {
      effect.effect();
    }
  }

  public static class SomeEvent {}
}
```

Comment: In case you want to autowire an `ApplicationEventPublisher` and look for a concrete implementation to provide when only a part of the application context is loaded, this `ApplicationContextRunner` is also the way to go!
e.g. `@SpringBootTest(classes=ApplicationContextRunner.class)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works! For others: This approach also suitable for Spring Modulith events tests _(beans with `@ApplicationModuleListener` annotation)_

Answer (score 6):

## Why I think it is justified to add another answer

The answer from [lane.maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995491/7082956) is *technically* correct but has one semantic error and one redundant annotation. It also lacks an explanation of why it does what it does.

And it is outdated for the usage with **JUnit 5**:

```java
// @SpringBootTest is overkill
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // instead of @RunWith
class EventPublisherTest {

   @Autowired 
   private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher; // shouldn't be final

   @MockBean
   private SomeDependency someDependency;

   @Test
   void test() {
      // Act
      publisher.publishEvent(new MyApplicationEvent(createMySource()));

      // Assert
      verify(someDependency).someMethod(); // times(1) is the default and can be omitted
   }
}
```

## Explanation

Although the instance of `someDependency` is a mock the test passes, because Spring is generating a [Proxy-Object](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring) which contains the logic for `@EventListener` which is being called from the framework, it is no mock. The proxy object then calls the mocked `someDependency` on which we verify the interaction.

### Testing the order of calls

I stumbled upon this question while looking for a possibility to test the execution order of two methods which both have an @EventListener to the same ApplicationEvents. Suppose they are called `someDepencency1` and `someDependency2` and I want to assert they are called in this exact order, then the test looked like that:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class EventPublisherTest {

   @Autowired 
   private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

   @MockBean
   private SomeDependency1 someDependency1;

   @MockBean
   private SomeDependency2 someDependency2;

   @Test
   void test() {
      // Arrange
      MyApplicationEvent myApplicationEvent = new MyApplicationEvent(createMySource());
      long timeoutDuration = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);

      // Act
      publisher.publishEvent(myApplicationEvent);

      // Assert
      InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(someDependency1, someDependency2);
      inOrder.verify(someDependency1, timeout(timeoutDuration)).someMethod();
      inOrder.verify(someDependency2, timeout(timeoutDuration)).someMethod();
      inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The option I took was to create a TestConfiguration and a listener within the test itself like this:

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RegistrationConfiguration.class, RegistrationTestConfiguration.class})
class RegistrationServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    @Autowired
    private AmazonDynamoDBAsync amazonDynamoDB;
    @Autowired
    private RegistrationRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    private String personaId;

    private RegistrationService testObj = null;

    @BeforeEach void setup() {
        RegistrationServiceDBHelper.initializeTable(dynamoDBMapper, amazonDynamoDB, repository);
        personaId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        testObj = new RegistrationService(repository, eventPublisher);
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    static class RegistrationTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        RegistrationServiceEventListener eventListener() {
            return new RegistrationServiceEventListener();
        }
    }


    @Component
    public static class RegistrationServiceEventListener {
        @TransactionalEventListener
        public void onPlayerRegisteredEvent(PlayerRegisteredEvent event) {
            log.info("Received new user event {}", event.personaId());
            assertThat(event.personaId()).isNotBlank();
        }
    }


    @DisplayName("given a persona id that is not registered")
    @Nested class WhenNoPlayerIsRegistered {

        @DisplayName("when a player is registered"
                + " then an event is raised")
        @Test void raisePlayerRegisteredEvent() {
            // When
            testObj.registerPlayer(personaId);
        }
    }
}
```