# object is not an instance of declaring class in JUnit

Tags: java

I want to create JUnit class for this code:

```
@Component
public class ReportingProcessor {

    @EventListener
    private void collectEnvironmentData() {
    }
}
```

I tried this implement this Junit test with reflation:

```
public class ReportingTest {

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

         Method m = ReportingProcessor.class.getDeclaredMethod("collectEnvironmentData", null);
         m.setAccessible(true);
         m.invoke(this);               
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at org.datalis.rest.api.server.reporting.ReportingTest.reportingTest(ReportingTest.java:15)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What do you think `m.invoke(this);` does/should do?

Answer (score -1):

This answer may help you, you are testing a Spring Bean. For improved support you should check out Spring testing guides:

[How to test Spring @EventListener method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950657/how-to-test-spring-eventlistener-method)