# How to check if @KafkaListener was invoked in integration test?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-kafka

I would like to write an integration test for whole kafka flow.

In my production code I have:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
public void listen(@Payload String payload) {
    log.debug("processing payload: '{}' ", payload);
    // business logic here
}
```

In my test code I use `KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;` to send messages to specific topic.

I would like to have a hook that would indicate that `@KafkaListener` was called.
I could insert some delay into test but it's a bad practice and I want to avoid it.

Is there any better way to wait for `@KafkaListener` being processed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950657/how-to-test-spring-eventlistener-method

Comment: @asolanki I test kafka events not spring application events

Comment: I think that @asolanki's point is that the same approach can be used. This is typical in unit testing, you mock the thing that interacts with the external service. In this case it would be Kafka that you are mocking. Then, after running the test you assert whether a particular thing was called, in your case KafkaListener. However, in your example I believe you want to test with a real Kafka environment. Is that correct?

Comment: But I don't want to unit test it - I want to have full integration tests with kafka instantiated with Testcontainers. Of course I could run my listener directly as unit, but it will miss the whole point of integration test

Answer (score 2):

If your listener invokes some service, you can inject a mock for that service and verify it was called.

Also, you can wrap your listener in the test case and add a count down latch.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783066/how-to-write-unit-test-for-kafkalistener/52784139#52784139) for an example.